# Block ChatGPT bot at an nginx level

Tags: nginx

I want to block access for ChatGPT for a whole website, but still allow it to see the robots.txt file located in the public root directory *(my robots.txt basically also tells ChatGPT not to crawl the site)*.

I am blocking it as follows:

```
# Disallow chatGPT bot
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "gptbot") {
        return 401;
    }
}
```

But I want it to be able to access the robots.txt file.

I tried doing:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "GPTBot") {
    if ($request_uri != /robots.txt) {
        return 403;  # Forbidden
    }
}
```

But it fails.

I also tried:

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "gptbot") {
        return 401;
    }
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

And also a variation of this using [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html):

```
map $http_user_agent $block_gptbot {
    default         0;
    ~*gptbot        1;
}

server {

location / {
    if ($block_gptbot) {
        return 401;
    }
}

...
```

But in both cases, the whole site is blocked. Means, gptbot cannot acces anything (it gets the 401), not even robots.txt.

Comment: Why double it up like this? OpenAI's bot respects robots.txt already.

Comment: @ceejayoz Makes sense, thanks for the feedback. And out of curiosity and to learn the abstract version of this issue for next time, how would you approach this case?

Comment: Allow the `robots.txt` URL using: `location = /robots.txt {}`

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith - But this also fails. I updated the question with more specific information.

Comment: If "the nginx server doesn't even start" - check the error log and test the configuration using  `nginx -t`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks, didn't know about that. There was a duplicate `location /` rule. Now there isn't, and the `location = /robots.txt {}` follows the block rule, but still robots.txt cannot be accessed. The whole site cannot be accessed by gpt bot.

Comment: In this specific case, isn't that what you want?

Comment: @ceejayoz In this specific case, I'd like chatgpt to still see the robots.txt. But I will just block the whole site and forget about it. Thanks!